# How to get the top 100 names in a collection

Tags: c++

I am creating a program where I am summarizing from a data file. The data file has information about first names, etc. The information are the fields in the csv file. The fields in the data file are included as instance variables in the class. I created setter and getter methods to return the data for one person. I created vectors to hold the collection of variables.

I am having trouble understanding how create a list of the 100 most common first names of all people in the collection. The list must be in descending order of occurrence.

I was able to print all the common names and its frequencies. But, I am unable to print the 100 most common names. I sorted the vector and got the following errors:

1. class `std::pair<const std::string, int>` has no member `begin` and `end`

Please help me resolve these issue. All processing of data in the vector must be done with iterators.I am not sure how to fix these issues since I am a beginner.

```
std::vector<std::string> commonNamesFirst; //vector

for (auto x : census) {
    commonNamesFirst.push_back(x.getFirstName()); //populate vector
}

std::map<std::string, int> frequencies; 

for (auto& x : census) { ++frequencies[x.getFirstName()]; }

for (auto& freq : frequencies) {
    sort(freq.begin(), freq.end(), greater <>()); //error, need to sort in descending order

    cout << freq.first << ": " << freq.second << endl; //print the 100 common names in descending order
}
```

Comment: `std::map` is sorted automatically, you don't need to (and you can't) sort it yourself. If you want to sort the data in a map you need to copy it to a vector first and then sort the vector.

Comment: Off-topic, but note that there are other ways of solving this problem, most notably by using a min-heap.  If the number of total items was huge, and you only want the top 100, then you would / should use a minheap.

Comment: @ChandMoon Copy the map data to a vector, sort the vector, print out the first 100 entries in the vector. Do you feel able to do those things?

Comment: @ChandMoon You should try, this is how you learn. If you're completely stuck then it might be best to find someone you can talk to face to face, a teacher or another student. Unfortunately this isn't a site where we will write your code for you.

Comment: @ChandMoon -- If you're a beginner, why not do an experiment?  Write a loop that prints out each of the entries in the map, and then figure out what to do with the data you see in the output.

Comment: Start with this `std::vector<std::string, int> sortedFrequencies;` Thats the vector you are going to copy the map data to and then sort.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::map<std::string, int> frequencies;
```

This is generally the right direction. You're using this to count how many times each word occurs.

```
for (auto& freq : frequencies) {
```

This iterates over ***each individual*** word and a count of how many times it occured. This no longer makes any logical sense. You are looking to find the 100 most common ones, the one with the highest count values. Iterating, and looking at each one individually, in the manner that's done here, does not make any sense.

```
sort(freq.begin(), freq.end(), greater <>());
```

`freq`, here, is a ***single*** word and how many times it occured. You are using `freq` to ***iterate*** over all of the `frequencies`. Therefore, this is just ***one*** of the words, and its frequency value. This is a ***single*** `std::pair` value. And it does not have anything called `begin`, or `end`. And that's what your compiler is telling you, directly.

Furthermore, you cannot `sort` a `std::map` in the first place. This is not a sortable container. The simplest option is to ***extract the contents*** if the now-complete map into something that's sortable. Like, for example, a vector:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> vfrequencies{
     frequencies.begin(),
     frequencies.end()
};
```

So, you've now copied the contents of a map into a vector. Not the most efficient approach, but a workable one.

And now, you can sort this vector. Rather easily.

However, as one last detail, you can't just drop `std::greater<>` and expect the right thing to happen.

You are looking to sort on the ***frequency count value only***, which is the `.second` of these `std::pair`s. A plain `std::greater` is not going to do this for you. The `std::greater` overload for a `std::pair` is not going to do what you think it will do, here.

You will need to provide your own custom lambda for the third parameter of `std::sort`, that compares the ***second*** value of the `std::pair`s in that vector.

And then, the first 100 most common words will be the first 100 values in the vector. Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (re-)sort `std::map`, you can copy frequencies in vector or `std::multimap` as intermediate:

```
std::map<std::string, int> frequencies;
for (auto& x : census) { ++frequencies[x.getFirstName()]; }

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> freqs{frequencies.begin(), frequencies.end()};

std::partial_sort(freqs.begin(), freqs.begin() + 100, freqs.end(),
                  [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return lhs.second > rhs.second; });
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
{
    std::cout << freqs[i].second << ":" << freqs[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on to @Michał Kaczorowski's answer, you are trying to sort the values in each pair instead of the pairs in the map. However, as Sam mentoined, you cannot sort an `std::map` (the internal implementation stores things sorted by the key value, or the name in this case). You'd have to get the values out of the map and sort them then, or use a priority queue and heapsort (faster constant factor), or a monotonic queue (linear time but harder to implement). Here is an example heapsort implementation:

```cpp
vector<string> commonNamesFirst; //vector

for (auto x : census) {
    commonNamesFirst.push_back(x.getFirstName()); //populate vector
}

std::map<std::string, int> frequencies; 

for (auto& x : census) { ++frequencies[x.getFirstName()]; }

std::priority_queue<pair<int, std::string> > top_names;  // put the frequency before the name to take advantage of default pair compare

for (auto& freq : frequencies) top_names.push(std::make_pair(freq.second, freq.first));
for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
{
    outputFile << top_names.top().second << ": " << top_names.top().first << endl; //print the 100 common names in descending order
    top_names.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get, says it all. You are trying to sort individual `std::pair`. I think the best way would be to `transform` your map into a `std::vector` of pairs and then `sort` that vector. Then just go through first 100 elements in a loop and print results.